# How can I run qemu with KVM over ssh?

Tags: ssh, qemu

When I run `qemu -cpu kvm64 -snapshot -hda binary.img` at a local console, the image boots and runs as I expect. However, when I log in via `ssh -C -X`, I see:

```
$ qemu -cpu kvm64 -snapshot -hda binary.img 
open /dev/kvm: Permission denied
Could not initialize KVM, will disable KVM support
qemu: pci_add_option_rom: failed to find romfile "pxe-rtl8139.bin"
```

(The `pxe-rtl8139` message is there when run locally as well, it doesn't seem to matter.)

Why does using SSH make a difference? How can I run `qemu` over SSH without needing root permissions?

Both machines are Ubuntu 11.10, qemu and qemu-kvm are 0.14.1+noroms-0ubuntu6.2

Comment: Your error message seems to indicate a permissions problem. Are you ssh in as the same user ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - yep, same user. Authenticated using keys, not password.

Comment: What are the ownership permissions on /dev/kvm and output of `id`

Comment: `/dev/kvm` is owned `root:kvm` and `id` says `uid=1000(jason) gid=1000(jason) groups=1000(jason),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),118(admin),124(sambashare)`

Comment: Add your user to the kvm group and it should then work.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - it worked, make that an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After additional information in the comments, You need to add your user to the kvm group.

Comment: Great! But why does it work for a local login? Some sort of PAM magic I'm guessing?

Comment: I am not sure why it worked locally, did you run it with sudo ?

Comment: Nope. Same as over SSH, just as my regular login.